# bootstrap select event parameters

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using the bootstrap select plugin (http://silviomoreto.github.io/) and I am handling the change event "changed.bs.select" to capture any selection changes. As per the documentation at https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/, " this event fires after the select's value has been changed. It passes through event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue. "

I would like to understand what the newValue and oldValue represent exactly. Because it is always the case where the new value is true and the oldValue is false.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate my point.

https://jsfiddle.net/muojdbh9/

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>

<div class="res">
Waiting for a change event
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".selectpicker").on('changed.bs.select', function (event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    $("div.res").html("newValue: " + newValue + "<BR>oldValue: " + oldValue);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error. It appears that `newValue` and `oldValue` do not behave as you may expect.
Both `newValue` and `oldValue` operate the same way.
The boolean values you are seeing refer to the previous and new state of the selected option.

`true` represented selected and `false` representing not selected.

**If the newly selected option was previously not in it's selected state, it will return like so:**

`newValue: true` and `oldValue: false`

**If the selected option was previously selected, it will return like so:**

`newValue: false` and `oldValue: true` Because it deselected the element.

This is addressed by caseyjhol here:

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1378/#issuecomment-216393099

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is just not behaving the way one would expect.

Answer (score 4):

If you like to have expected behaviour simply change

`that.$element.trigger('changed.bs.select', [clickedIndex, $option.prop('selected'), state]);`

to

`that.$element.trigger('changed.bs.select', [clickedIndex, $option.prop('value'), prevValue]);`

in your bootstrap-select.js

Comment: This is a good suggestion as well, **+1**, however I am not very keen on changing 3rd party libraries code to avoid any problems when I update to a newer version in the future

Answer (score 2):

`newValue` represents the newly selected option's "selected" property, while `oldValue` represents the previously selected option's "selected" property. Since the new option will always be selected and the old option will always be unselected, they return true and false respectively. This is probably an error on the part of the developers of bootstrap select - it seems they would have intended to pass either the option elements themselves or the options values, not their "selected" properties.

Comment: I agree it must be an error because I cannot find a good explanation for this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem also. Thanks TAGraves for the explanation of what's happening. Ended up using a solution like this:

**jQuery**

```
$(".selectpicker").on('changed.bs.select', function (event, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    var Value = $(".selectpicker option:selected").val()
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` should do the same, with less code.